# Minitest test responses don't work for explicit status code numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

When I write.

```
assert_response :success, @response.body.to_s
```

I get a nice error message I had planted in my code. 
But when I try to run this similar code using explicit status code numbers such as...

```
assert_response(422), @response.body.to_s
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_end
    assert_response(422) @response.body.to_s`

What is the proper syntax to impliment this type of code?

Comment: Try `assert_response(422, @response.body.to_s)ˋ or ˋassert_response 422, @response.body.to_s`. Refer to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert_response 422, @response.body.to_s
```

Putting parentheses around the first parameter is confusing the ruby method call to think `(422)` represents all the parameters it needs. Then the extra `, @response.body.to_s` is throwing a syntax error.

EDIT:

If you wanted to use parentheses, you can also use this format.

```
assert_response(422, @response.body.to_s)
```